# NoSQL Solution for a Hosted Site

Tags: php, nosql

I'm operating on a hosted site without the option to install software packages (i.e.; unsupported binaries) and I'm interested in the benefits of NoSQL for a potentially database intensive site.

Are there any solutions of NoSQL that can easily be implemented with little-to-no sysadmin involvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the NoSQL databases have hosted versions available.

[MongoHQ](https://www.mongohq.com/) is an example of one for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using 3rd party hosted DB solutions? For instance Google hosts their App Engine "platform" along with its Datastore. (http://code.google.com/appengine/)

Comment: I have thought about 3rd party solutions, but the client isn't receptive to addition cost requirements.

Comment: If it can't be 3rd party and can't be installed on the server, and you dpn't want to worry about SysAdmin fun then it sort of seems that it can't be done. (standing by to be corrected)

Comment: @JohnGiotta Agreeing with James here. You're client doesn't seem to be very realistic in their requirements vs. restrictions. You might want to outline the options for them so they can decide whats the most acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned there are many hosted solutions that tend to be located on Rackspace Cloud Servers, or Amazon EC2 servers which you should be able to hook into. As a bonus many of them them (at least CouchDB and Mongo) eiher support natively or have extension that allow queries to be made over HTTP which should simplify connecting to them greatly. These hosted solutions manage 99% of the daily (and general) sysadmin faff so that you just worry about creating the database and reading and writing data to it.
(Just don't forget to allow your currents servers IP access to the hosted nosql DB when you wonder why it doesn't work)

CouchDB examples
http://cloudant.com/
http://www.iriscouch.com/

Mongo example
https://mongolab.com/home/